# WooCommerce Email Notification - Change footer content based on order billing location

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I am trying to change the email footer content in WooCommerce notification emails based on the current order's billing location. The reason for this is because I need to display different distributor business details if the order comes from a person in New Zealand, Australia or Europe.

I have a cookie that stores the user's current region. This is set using this service: http://ipinfo.io/

functions.php file code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'location_setcookies' );
function gng_setcookies() {

if(isset($_COOKIE['country_set'])) {
    $country_set = $_COOKIE['country_set'];

    if($country_set == true) {

        $cur_country = $_COOKIE['cur_country'];
        $cur_region = $_COOKIE['cur_region'];

    }

} else {

    $country = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/country");
    $cur_country = trim($country);

    setcookie( 'country_set', 'false', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );

    if($cur_country == "NZ") {
        setcookie( 'cur_country', $cur_country, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        setcookie( 'cur_region', 'NZ', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN ); 
        $cur_region = "NZ";
    } elseif ($cur_country == "AU") {
        setcookie( 'cur_country', $cur_country, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        setcookie( 'cur_region', 'AU', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        $cur_region = "AU";
    } elseif ($cur_country == "AT" || "BE" || "BG" || "CY" || "CZ" || "DK" || "EE" || "FI" || "FR" || "DE" || "GR" || "HU" || "IE" || "IT" || "LV" || "LT" || "LU" || "MT" || "NL" || "PL" || "PT" || "RO" || "SK" || "SI" || "ES" || "SE" || "GB") {
        setcookie( 'cur_country', $cur_country, time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        setcookie( 'cur_region', 'EU', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        $cur_region = "EU";
    } else {
        setcookie( 'cur_country', 'NZ', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        setcookie( 'cur_region', 'NULL', time() + 3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        $cur_region = "NULL";
    }

}

 }

add_filter( 'cur_region_val', 'return_cur_region_val' );
function return_cur_region_val( $arg = '' ) {

if(isset($_COOKIE['country_set'])) {

    $cur_region = $_COOKIE['cur_region'];

    return $cur_region;

} else {

    $country = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/country");
    $cur_country = trim($country);

    if($cur_country == "NZ") {
        return "NZ";
    } elseif ($cur_country == "AU") {
        return "AU";
    } elseif ($cur_country == "AT" || "BE" || "BG" || "CY" || "CZ" || "DK" || "EE" || "FI" || "FR" || "DE" || "GR" || "HU" || "IE" || "IT" || "LV" || "LT" || "LU" || "MT" || "NL" || "PL" || "PT" || "RO" || "SK" || "SI" || "ES" || "SE" || "GB") {

        return "EU";
    } else {
        return  "NULL";
    }

} 

}
```

I have tried using the cookie value to determine which email footer content should be displayed but it does not work as expected.

email-footer.php code:

```
$cur_region = apply_filters( 'cur_region_val', '' );

if($cur_region == 'NZ') {

    echo '<p>New Zealand Business Details</p>';

} elseif($cur_region == 'AU') {

    echo '<p>Australian Business Details</p>';

} elseif($cur_region == 'EU') {

    echo '<p>Europe Business Details</p>';

}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction. I am assuming I need to use a WooCommernce hook or use the order object somehow to retrieve the current order's billing location.

EDIT: I was going to use the order shipping location but I think it would be best to use the order billing location or my cookie value.

Thanks